# Copy characters from char array to char array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, char

I have a char array with the size of 128. I want to copy the first 32 to another char array. This is how i'm trying to do it:

```
char ticket[128];
data.readBytes(ticketLength, (BYTE*)ticket);
char sessionID[32];
strcpy(sessionID, ticket);

int userID = bdAuthService::checkLogin(sessionID);
```

The contents of "ticket" are `"11aa14462ac96a9b389686672b99fa9e1IvtooKO6eVxVHO6URIQld8jFaceTaker"` and when i'm trying to pass the sessionID to the checkLogin function it gets the same contents as ticket `"11aa14462ac96a9b389686672b99fa9e1IvtooKO6eVxVHO6URIQld8jFaceTaker"`.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Looks like a bad mixture of zero terminated and  non zero terminated strings

Comment: You better decide first whether to program in C or C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `memcpy` function instead.

```
memcpy( sessionID, ticket, sizeof( sessionID )  );
```

Take into account that sessionID won;t contain a string. It will contain "raw" characters.

As for function `strcpy` then it is designed to copy strings that is a sequence of characters termintaed by zero.
So in case of your code fragment it will copy as many characters as there are characters in `ticket` before the character with value '\0' provided that such a character is present in `ticket` .

Comment: When i use memcpy like you said the sid inside the called functions gets the value "593378e02614ebf8468cb67ca319bedaðúÙ,ûÙ@
wÞUVSþÿÿÿ„úÙ<" So it gets the bytes i want but adding useless stuff..

Comment: @BillAdonopoulos: because it is not null terminated

Comment: @BillAdonopoulos What is useless stuff? You said that you need to copy 32 characters. So where are the useless stuff from?

Comment: So how can i make it null terminated? If i set sessionID[33] i get null terminated string but it gets 33 characters not 32 that i need and with [32] it's not null terminated

Comment: @BillAdonopoulos I think that the problem is not with this copy operation. The problem is how ypu are using the result string further in your code.

Comment: @BillAdonopoulos It is not clear now what you are trying to achieve. Whether you indeed need to copy 32 characters or something else. You could copy 31 characters and set the 32nd character to zero.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use strncpy which allows you to specify the number of bytes to copy.